# Oracle Update success but not getting updated in table

Tags: sql

I have updated a row in a table using this SQL query:

```
UPDATE fruits 
SET f_name='Mangosteen' 
WHERE f_ID='1'
```

and the query returns,

> 1 rows updated

but in the table the change is not getting reflected. The table is accepting manual changes but not through the query, what can be the reason.

I tried rebuilding the table, but it still fails.

Comment: Please post a complete "log" of the UPDATE and corresponding SELECT statement from a SQL*Plus session (use Copy & Paste). If you are committing without an error, the data must have changed.

Comment: Do you have triggers on `fruits`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you `commit`ted the transaction?

Comment: yea i did! still its not reflecting in teh table

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you [COMMIT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/commit_statement.htm) the changes.

Comment: Then the only other explanation is that you are committing to a different database and you are checking another database. Are you getting any errors ? How are you running your queries?

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting to the database ? Refreshing the table view? If nothing else works, restart the PC! Works every time :D

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: `Create trigger before update on fruits begin :new.f_name = :old.f_name; end;`

Comment: Hi Ran,
I tried all that stuff, it didnt wrk out! 
so created the table again, its working fine nw. thnks for the answers :)
-jeh!

Comment: @Benoit nice try, but he says the table's accepting 'manual changes'. JEH , by 'manual changes', do you mean that when doing it in a grid of a sql front-end (sql developer, squirrel, toad, ...), the changes get commited?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on column ISTLIEFERTERMIN in table T_AUFTRAG and then remembered the trigger:

```
create trigger tU1_T_AUFTRAG before UPDATE on T_AUFTRAG for each row
begin
if :NEW.ABGESCHLOSSEN <> 1 and :NEW.KOMMNR not like '%ANFRAG%' then 
       :NEW.ISTLIEFERTERMIN := NULL; 
    end if; 
end;
```

:-D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was another process I wasn't aware of that was setting my column to the old value very frequently giving the impression of an update not taking any effect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24374818)

Comment: Had exactly same problem and this was the solution for me - just saying... Anyway - what was the question? - I can't see any.